# Jquery on hover not functioning

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, hover, jquery-events

I'm changing my codes to be compatible with jQuery 1.8 and I'm stuck with this `hover` which doesn't work. When I used then same thing with a `click` it worked. Here is my code, can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
$(document).on('hover', '.top-level', function (event) {
  $(this).find('.actionfcnt').show();
  $(this).find('.dropfcnt').show();
}, function () {
  $(this).find('.dropfcnt').hide('blind', function () {
    $('.actionfcnt').hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: What happens using "mouseover" instead of "hover"?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

***Deprecated as of jQuery 1.8***: The name "hover" used as a shorthand for the string "mouseenter mouseleave". It attaches a single event handler for those two events, and the handler must examine event.type to determine whether the event is mouseenter or mouseleave. **Do not confuse** the "hover" pseudo-event-name with the .hover() method, which accepts one or two functions.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/on/#additional-notes

That pretty much says it all, you cant use "hover" for that:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','.top-level', function (event) {
    $( this ).find('.actionfcnt').show();
    $( this ).find('.dropfcnt').show();
}).on('mouseleave','.top-level',  function(){
    $( this ).find('.dropfcnt').hide('blind', function(){
        $('.actionfcnt').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: suppose there is a ajax call and the content of .top-level is replaced with new then also this mouseenter would work?

Comment: @param Yes this will work fine, this syntax still fully supports delegated events (events triggered by elements which weren't in DOM at time of function def). This will accomplish what you want for dynamically generated elements.

Comment: thanks you for the answer :) just checked it using dynamic content , its working perfect

Comment: @ParamVeer Glad it was useful! :)

Comment: This thing was burning my head for days, i was 100% that my code was working and it did when I replaced "hover" with mouseenter. I still don't get why they removed when they could just improve the name or at least throw a damn error. Anyway Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 12):

there is no "hover" event.
there is .hover() function that takes 2 callbacks (as in your example).

Comment: Imagine if all answers could be this concise and straight to the point. Great job!

Answer (score 5):

`.on` function has only 3 parameters : http://api.jquery.com/on/

If you don't need your handlers be bound to dynamically added elements as well, then you may use the good old `hover` function with 2 event handlers.

```
$('.top-level').hover(function (event) { 
  $(this).find('.actionfcnt').show();
  $(this).find('.dropfcnt').show();
}, function (event) {   
  $(this).find('.dropfcnt').hide('blind', function(){
    $('.actionfcnt').hide();
  });
});​
```

By the way, `$(selector).hover(handlerIn, handlerOut)` is shorthand for `$(selector).mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);`.

If you need to, then use `on` for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.top-level', function (event) { 
  $(this).find('.actionfcnt').show();
  $(this).find('.dropfcnt').show();
}).on('mouseleave', '.top-level', function (event) {   
  $(this).find('.dropfcnt').hide('blind', function(){
    $('.actionfcnt').hide();
  });
});​
```

Comment: so i cant use hover? instead i have to use 'mouseenter'

Comment: thanks i appreciate your answer and @nbrooks answer both . both are correct , thanks for such detail explanation

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
$(".top-level").on({
    mouseenter: function (event) {
        $( this ).find('.actionfcnt').show();
        $( this ).find('.dropfcnt').show();
    },
    mouseleave: function (event) {
        $( this ).find('.dropfcnt').hide('blind', function(){
            $('.actionfcnt').hide();
        });
    }
});
```

OR

```
$(".top_level").on("hover", function(event) {
  if(event.type == "mouseenter") {
    $( this ).find('.actionfcnt').show();
    $( this ).find('.dropfcnt').show();
  }
  else if (event.type == "mouseleave") {
    $( this ).find('.dropfcnt').hide('blind', function(){
        $('.actionfcnt').hide();
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('.top-level').hover(function (event) {
        $( this ).find('.actionfcnt').show();
        $( this ).find('.dropfcnt').show();
}, function(){
        $( this ).find('.dropfcnt').hide('blind', function(){
            $('.actionfcnt').hide();
        });
});
```