# jQuery hover is not working when load data for autocomplete

Tags: jquery, hover

This code is not working:

```
$("ul.lst li").hover(function (event) {   
    $('#span').text($(this).index());
});
```

When use the same code and hard coded html, mouse-over works smooth and give the hovered `li` index.
What am I missing?

```js
var records = [];
var selectedIndex = null;
var selectedRecord = null;
var fRecords = [];
var autocomplete = function (event, el) {   
    var search = el.value;

    if (event.key === "ArrowDown") {
       
        if(records == null) return;  // if no result

        if (records.length > 0 && selectedIndex == null) {
            selectedIndex = 0;           
        }
        else if (records.length > 0 && selectedIndex < records.length - 1) {
            selectedIndex++;
        }
        changeClass(selectedIndex);
    }
    else if (event.key === "ArrowUp") {
        if (records == null) return;  // if no result

        if (records.length > 0 && selectedIndex == null) {
            selectedIndex = 0;
        }
        else if (records.length > 0 && selectedIndex > 0) {
            selectedIndex--;
        }
        changeClass(selectedIndex);
    }
    else if (event.key === "Enter") {

    }
    else {
        selectedIndex = null;
        selectedRecord = null;

        if (records.length === 0) {
            $.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments')
                .done(function (data) {
                   
                    records = data;
                    // sort by name
                    sort(records);

                    showAutoComplete(records, search);
                });
        }
        else {
            showAutoComplete(records, search);
        }
    }
}

var showAutoComplete = function (data, search) {
    search = search.toUpperCase();
    fRecords = [];
    $.each(data, function (k, v) {
        if (v.name.toUpperCase().startsWith(search)) {
            fRecords.push(v);
            if (fRecords.length > 9)
                return false;
        }
    });

    $("ul.lst").empty();
    if (fRecords.length > 0)
        $("ul.lst").addClass("suggest");
    else
        $("ul.lst").removeClass("suggest");
    $.each(fRecords, function (key, value) {
        $("ul.lst").append('<li>' + value.name + '</li>');
    });
}

var sort = function (records) {
    records.sort(function (a, b) {
        var nameA = a.name.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
        var nameB = b.name.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
        if (nameA < nameB) {   return -1; }
        if (nameA > nameB) { return 1; }
        // names must be equal
        return 0;
    });   
}

var changeClass = function (index) {

    selectedRecord = records[selectedIndex];
    $("ul.lst>li.active").removeClass("active");
    if (selectedIndex != null) {
        $($("ul.lst>li")[selectedIndex]).addClass("active");
        $('#company').val($($("ul.lst>li")[selectedIndex]).text());
    }
}

$('#company').keyup(function () { autocomplete(event, this); });

$('#company').blur(function(){
    $("ul.lst").removeClass("suggest");
})

//$("ul.autocomplete li").hover(function (event) {
//        debugger;
//        selectedIndex = $(this).index();
//        changeClass(selectedIndex);
//        console.log(selectedIndex);
    
//});


$("ul.lst li").hover(function (event) {
   
    $('#span').text($(this).index());

});
```

```css
ul.lst {
    display: none;
}
ul.lst.suggest {
        display:block;
       
    }
    ul.lst li {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 7px 12px;
        border: 1px solid #bbb;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
     ul.lst > li.active {
        background-color: #ffcc66;
        color: #000;
       z-index:1000;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class='col-sm-10 offset-col-1 mt-4'>
  <strong>Type something for auto complete</strong>
  <span id='span'></span>
  <input type='text' id='company' class='form-control'>
  <ul class='lst'></ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("ul.lst li").hover` adds the `hover` event handler only to the elements existing at the time when it’s called.

To make it apply to all the elements, even the ones added later, use `on`, like this:

```
$("ul.lst").on('mouseover', 'li', function (event) { {   
    $('#span').text($(this).index());
});
```

In the selector, you specify the parent element that exists at the moment of the script call (here, it’s `ul.lst`), and later, as the second parameter, you  specify additional selector inside it (`li`). It will work on any `li` added inside `ul.lst` at any time.

Comment: Actually you can't bind `hover` event like this. You have to use `mouseenter` or `mouseover`. Reason is mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260235/jquery-on-hover-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Probably is because the event is been called before the elements are loaded. You should wait for the document to load before adding the event, like so:

```
$(function() {
  $("ul.lst li").hover(function (event) {   
     $('#span').text($(this).index());
  });
});
```