# Play audio on hover with Jquery

Tags: jquery, audio

I have an audio file and want that it's playing as soon as the cursor is hovering the div the audio file is placed in.

For any reason its only working with a click function but not with a hover/mouseenter function.

This is working:

```
$(".interview").on("click",function(){
   $(this).find("#audio")[0].play();
});
```

This isn't working:

```
$(".interview").on("hover",function(){
   $(this).find("#audio")[0].play();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Hover is Deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. ref [Jquery on hover not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260235/jquery-on-hover-not-working)

```
 $(".interview").hover(function(){
       $(this).find("#audio")[0].play();
  });
```

(or) use `mouseenter` event ref https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

```js
$(document).on('mouseenter','.interview',function(){
 alert(1)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="interview">hover me</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately this is also not working. :/

Comment: Thanks. So I also tried the alert and it's working. But not with the audio file playing … any idea? its weird!

Comment: this is a browser security constraint, and no audio could be played without a click.